# Mapping all ordered pairs of a Java enum to a value

Tags: java, dictionary, enums

I have a Spring Boot application where I hold bank accounts with a certain balance and in a certain currency, and can `POST` transactions between any two bank accounts. For currencies, I have an `enum` with about 300 currency identifiers as per ISO 4217:

```java
public enum Currency {
    AFN,
    EUR,
    ALL,
    DZD,
    USD,
    .
    .
    .
}
```

To make a transaction between two accounts with different currency identifiers, I want to take into consideration the buy/sell price of different currencies, which for this application can be random floats. So effectively I'm looking for a `Map` with pairs of `Currency` instances as keys and `float` or `double` as values.

What is a quick and elegant way to do this? I'd really rather not iterate through the entire `enum` with a double `for` loop.

Comment: "I'd really rather not iterate through the entire enum with a double for loop" Why not?

Comment: Monetary values -> use `BigDecimal` to mitigate problems with precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a Map-based solution if you first define a CurrencyPair class to represent the pair of currencies:

```
public class CurrencyPair {
    private Currency fromCurrency;
    private Currency toCurrency;

    public CurrencyPair(Currency fromCurrency, Currency toCurrency) {
        this.fromCurrency = fromCurrency;
        this.toCurrency = toCurrency;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CurrencyPair that = (CurrencyPair) o;
        return fromCurrency == that.fromCurrency && toCurrency == that.toCurrency;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(fromCurrency, toCurrency);
    }
}
```

Next, create a Map with CurrencyPair keys and Double values to store the buy/sell prices:

```
Map<CurrencyPair, Double> currencyPrices = new HashMap<>();
```

To populate the map with random prices for all possible currency pairs, you can iterate over the Currency enum and generate random prices for each pair of currencies:

```
Random random = new Random();

for (Currency fromCurrency : Currency.values()) {
    for (Currency toCurrency : Currency.values()) {
        CurrencyPair currencyPair = new CurrencyPair(fromCurrency, toCurrency);
        double price = random.nextDouble(); // Generate a random price
        currencyPrices.put(currencyPair, price);
    }
}
```

Now you can access the buy/sell prices by providing the appropriate CurrencyPair key:

```
CurrencyPair currencyPair = new CurrencyPair(Currency.USD, Currency.EUR);
double price = currencyPrices.get(currencyPair);
```

That's it. I think that this Map-based solution is a lot easier to read than a Streams-based one.

Comment: Thanks! Seems rather obvious to encapsulate a pair of `Currency` instances and just use a map with this new class as the key type, when you're given this idea. Perhaps an equivalent solution would be to use a javafx.util.Pair. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's better to use Java 8's Stream API and Collectors!

let me give you an example,

```
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CurrencyMapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // map with pairs of currency instances as keys and random float values
        Map<Pair<Currency, Currency>, Float> currencyMap = Stream.of(Currency.values())
                .flatMap(currency1 -> Stream.of(Currency.values())
                        .map(currency2 -> new Pair<>(currency1, currency2)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(pair -> pair, CurrencyMapExample::getRandomFloat,
                        (value1, value2) -> value1, () -> new EnumMap<>(Pair.class)));

        // currency map
        currencyMap.forEach((pair, value) -> System.out.println(pair + " : " + value));
    }

    // generate a random float value
    private static Float getRandomFloat(Pair<Currency, Currency> pair) {
        // replace this with your code to generate random float for each pair of currencies
        return (float) Math.random();
    }

    // pair class to represent a pair of currencies
    static class Pair<T, U> {
        private final T first;
        private final U second;

        public Pair(T first, U second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        public T getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

        public U getSecond() {
            return second;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + first + ", " + second + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

you can create a `Map` with a pair of `Currency` instances as a key by using the `EnumMap` class in Java!

good luck!

Comment: This actually creates a `Map` with just a single `Currency` as a a key and a single `Float` as a value. This _could_ work if I considered one global `Currency` to compare all other `Currency` instances with (e.g `USD`), but I was wondering if I could perhaps make a `Map` with a PAIR of `Currency` instances as  a key.

Comment: Yes, now that makes more sense. I will be selecting the other reply as the accepted answer based only on readability; they are both correct.